# Weird behaviour of RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I'm developing portal in MVC 3. Have controller (`MyController`) with three methods `Add` (get and post verssion) and `Index` and part of add method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual RedirectToRouteResult AddItem(Item item)
{
    (...)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Simple? Not fot me:)
Item is added properly and when redirecting comes url looks like:

MyController/Index

and not:

mySite/MyController/Index

and of course that is bad news. This situation happens only in one case in one place in the whole portal. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved-i had to change order of routemaps in global.asax -request was catched by wrong map.

Answer (score 0):

What you get as a return is a relative path, relative to your current path.

Comment: Sorry but Your answer is not helpful. I still dont know why it happens,dont know the way how to fix it etc.

Comment: There are workarounds I can think of. But for the beginning, what's wrong with a relative URL? It redirects the user just fine.

Comment: Because i see in the browser only: MyController/Index not mySite/MyController/Index- and of course i get "page not found"

Comment: Oh, that's probably because the URL began with `/`... didn't tell that :-)